# Accessing command line arguments from eof with JFLEX

Tags: java, jflex

Im writing a small lexical analyzer which needs to write some outputs to a file. Once Im done scanning im creating an output file 
`PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(args[0].substring(0,4)+"output.txt");`

So essentially im trying to use the prefix of my input file as the prefix of my output. This statement is located in `%eof{ %eof}`

```
error: cannot find symbol 
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(args[0].substring(0,4)+"output.txt");
                                     ^ 
symbol: variable args 
location: class classname
```

However I cannot see args from the eof section. How could I access the command line arguments from `eof` in jflex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was with the `%standalone` option. It was generating a main method automatically putting the argv list out of scope.

Removing this option and defining my own main method did the trick, though I did also have to define my own file reader and error handling this way